# Today I can't access the Internet

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, wired

yesterday I had no problems, but today my internet connection doesn't work (both wireless and wired). I have no clue what the problem is, any suggestions?

Comment: The other devices I use connect perfectly though (PC and phone), I only have problems on my laptop.

Comment: Is Network Manager active?

Comment: Hmm, I tried to find it but can't see it anywhere.

Comment: On the top bar, is there an icon showing an up arrow and a down arrow? That is the symbol for the network manager. You can also check the status by opening a terminal window Ctrl+Alt+t and typing in the command sudo ifconfig which will list the status of the interfaces.

Comment: No, Graham, there is no such icon. Thanks for your efforts but I decided to install the latest Ubuntu version. Mine is old and I am sure when I updated something must have gone wrong with some of the files.

Comment: So now it works?

Comment: Yes, it worked after the new installation.